# Run testNG with env variable defined in properties file (IntelliJ)

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, testng

I am running my tests with Maven (in IntelliJ):

```
clean test -U -Pprofilename -Dtest.suite=suite.xml
```

this, as you can see, use a profile where the right property file is used for env variable.

How can I run the same suite.xml not using Maven command but just trough the ide(in IntelliJ), right-click -> run and telling it to use the right properties file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a run configuration for that:

- Open menu `Run` / `Edit Configurations...`
- Add new configuration (click + icon, or press ⌘N), then select `Maven`
- Specify your working directory
- Fill up the `Command line` field with your command
- Give a name to your configuration and click `Ok`

Now you should be able to run your tests using IntelliJ IDEA UI, by clicking the green triangle on the toolbar.

You can add as many configurations as you need. With different properties, environments, tags, etc.

Comment: Yes I know this way but what I mean is to run the test clicking directly on them and selecting run. I see that is the only way to show in the console the tests result. With you proposed way I cannot see test result in console.

Comment: @StefanoMaglione, could you please check the `Run` tab at the bottom edge of the IDEA? Because console output is supposed to be there.

Comment: It is written only "Failed to execute goal mave-surefire-plugin:test There are test failures". If I go to the index.html surefire reports I can see it but I would like to see it directly in Intellij